# The installation directory contains different application install4j

Tags: patch, install4j

I am getting the following error when I apply a patch created in Install4j. The existing installation also created in Install4j:

The installation directory contains different application.
The installation cannot be performed.

Can someone tell me what is the root cause for this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Your patch installer has a different application ID than the original installer.

Under Installer->Update Options, you can check and change the application ID. If you set the ID of the patch installer to the same as the original installer, the warning will go away.